# search multiple columns as if it was one column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that stores email in 3 diffrent columns 
name host and domain. 
I want to join those columns to create one column so i can search by a full email adress. 
just like

```
SELECT * FROM email_eml WHERE (all the columns combined) = $email;
```

the email is stored without a . and a @ in neither of the columns i would like the final result to contain those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM email_eml WHERE CONCAT( name, '@', host, '.', domain ) = $email
```

See the doc (assuming you're using MySQL) for the CONCAT function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

However:

1. Don't use `*`. It's terrible for performance.
2. I sure hope your `$email` variable is escaped and free of SQL injection risks. If it's not, use prepared statements.

Comment: need to wait 5 minutes untill i can accept an answer but i need to go eat. I will accept it today in the evening most likely ;/

Comment: No problem, take your time to see if another good suggestion comes in. @YaK's answer might be better suited for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

In order for MySQL to use indexes (you did index these columns, didn't you?), I'd rather split your input e-mail address, and then search on each field separately, that is:

```
SELECT CONCAT(name, '@', host, '.', domain) AS email
WHERE name = 'user' AND host = 'mysite' AND domain = 'com'
```

Do you really need to keep the three e-mail address components separated in your database? Otherwise, just store complete e-mails.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM email_eml WHERE name+'@'+host+'.'+domain = '$email';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CONCAT()` [function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat). 
Then your request will be :

```
SELECT * FROM email_eml WHERE CONCAT(name,'@',host,'.',domain) = $email
```